# Where does pip get the info of the target directory?

Tags: python, pip

I downloaded and installed the python version 3.7.7 of the **Windows x86 executable installer** from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ to a folder D:/python3.7.7.

After this, i copied the contents to another folder D:/binaries/python. Now whenever i try to pip install any package, like

```
pip install certifi
```

it basically **still installs it in D:/python3.7.7**.

I understand that this behavior can be overridden by using a `--target` option along with the pip  command but this not permanently change it and needs to be remembered and done for every pip install command.

Mentioning it in the pip.ini file is not an option since I dont have access to C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini.

Is there any other way **to permanently change the installation target folder** to D:/binaries/python for all future installations? I think pip must be reading it from one of the .py files or config files within the directory which I can edit.

Comment: can you check your environmental variables? (press the windows key and type "environment" is the fastest way). if the old path is still there replace it with the new one

Comment: @Finn no, my env variables haven't been modified. Also I have multiple versions of python in the system.

Comment: can you try to set the variables to "D:/binaries/python/Scripts" and  "D:/binaries/python". If you have multiple python versions make sure those are mentioned first.

Comment: Why not reinstalling Python3.7.7 to `D:/binaries/python` ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer This is not just in 1 machine that I have to do this. Anyway I believe there must a different soultion